# How to check if an array includes any two particular strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, include, indexof

```
handleDropdown = (dropdown) => {
        dropdown.map(drop => {
            if (drop.value.includes('destroyed') && drop.value.includes('damaged')) {
                console.log("working")
              }
        })
    }
```

I need to check if both "destroyed" and "damaged" are present in an array and return true. If I check any one condition using includes it is working fine, I'm not sure how to check two particular two elements is present in an array. I need help in solving this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `drop.value` is the array, that's the general way you would do it (hopefully doing something with whatever's returned from the `.map` too), can you post a [MCVE] so we can see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You may create an array of values to check and use `.every()` to test their existence in your data array.

```js
let data = ['a', 'b', 'destroyed', 'damaged', 'y', 'z'];
let valuesToCheck = ['destroyed', 'damaged'];

if(valuesToCheck.every(s => data.includes(s))) {
  console.log('It is working');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following:

```
const joined = dropdown.join();
return joined.includes('destroyed') && joined.includes('damaged')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) as well

```js
let data = ['a', 'b', 'destroyed', 'damaged', 'y', 'z'];

var result = data.indexOf('destroyed')> -1 && data.indexOf('damaged') > -1;

if(result)
  {
    console.log("It is working");
  }
```